# Updating existing entities in Entity Framework 6 code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an issue updating an existing entity in Entity Framework 6.

My generic update method is as follows:

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null) 
       throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

where the constructor is:

```
protected IContext _context;
protected IDbSet<T> _dbset;

public EntityService(IContext context)
{
    _context = context;
    _dbset = _context.Set<T>();
}
```

`IContext` is basically an interface of `DbContext`.

Now when trying to update I get the following error;

> InnerException = {"The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN
>   KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Appointment_dbo.Driver_DriverID\". The
>   conflict occurred in database \"DEVDB\", table \"dbo.Driver\", column
>   'id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Now the classes (reduced for brevity) are:

```
public partial class Appointment : AuditableEntity<int>
{
        public override int ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AppointmentType")]
        public int AppointmentTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual AppointmentType AppointmentType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AppointmentStatus")]
        public int AppointmentStatusID { get; set; }
        public virtual AppointmentStatus AppointmentStatus { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Driver")]
        public int? DriverID { get; set; }
        public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Vehicle")]
        public int? VehicleID { get; set; }
        public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have tried passing the result in through both entities.

i.e. VehicleID = 1 with Vehicle = null, VehicleID = null with Vehicle = VehicleEntity, and also together.

See the screenshot of the entity contents example:

[image: Screenshot of debug entity]

Any ideas why this is occurring please?

Comment: You are passing `DriverID=0` that I think is the main cause of Exception

Answer (score 2):

It's occuring because `DriverID` is `0`, but there is no `Driver` in the DB with an ID of `0`.  Since `DriverID` is nullable, you can probably get away with a `DriverID` of `null`

I can't elaborate much more on that unless I see what happens before you call the `Update` method.

Comment: @Matthew: you could probably get rid of `DriverID` from your `Appointment` class - EF Code First will take care of creating the FK for you. Similarly, you could remove other FK properties you created. Navigation properties would be enough to get the job done and EF Code First will take care of the rest.

Comment: Couldn't see the wood for the trees. Sorry.